# How can I specify a local gem in my Gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler

I'd like Bundler to load a local gem. Is there an option for that? Or do I have to move the gem folder into the .bundle directory?

Answer (score 668, accepted):

I believe you can do this:

```
gem "foo", path: "/path/to/foo"
```

Comment: A hard-coded path is fine for a quick hack session, but bloudermilk's local gem solution is more effective for projects under version control. It lets you keep checking in both projects - gem and project using the gem - such that others can don't have to check out the gem source or share the same paths.

Comment: You can make this slightly cleaner by using a .gitignored symlink to your local gem in your project directory -- that way you can use source control on both projects separately and others can do the same without having an identical directory structure.

Comment: Something to watch out for might be Spring.  If you are using a local path for your gem you could notice cached versions of your local gem like I did in rails console.  If it doesn't seem like your local gem changes are being picked up  try `spring stop` to see if it is indeed the issue.

Comment: Adding the local gem path to config/spring.rb seems to help pickup your local gem changes after restarting rails console/server.

Comment: Way better way of doing it this here: https://rossta.net/blog/how-to-specify-local-ruby-gems-in-your-gemfile.html

Comment: This is a perfectly fine way of doing it if you are testing local development of a gem on a larger project. In this case, this is the "better" way to do it then having to push to a repository to test local changes.

Comment: **NOTE:** You cannot specify the `branch` to use when using `path`, so make sure the correct branch is checked out in the local file system when doing this.

Answer (score 283):

In addition to specifying the path (as Jimmy mentioned) you can also force Bundler to use a local gem *for your environment only* by using the following configuration option:

```
$ bundle config set local.GEM_NAME /path/to/local/git/repository
```

This is extremely helpful if you're developing two gems or a gem and a rails app side-by-side.

Note though, that this only works when you're already using git for your dependency, for example:

```
# In Gemfile
gem 'rack', :github => 'rack/rack', :branch => 'master'

# In your terminal
$ bundle config set local.rack ~/Work/git/rack
```

As seen on [the docs](https://bundler.io/guides/git.html#local).

Comment: I am having issues with this because I am using `BUNDLE_PATH` (building a package for distribution). When doing what you suggested, or Jimmy's answer, it only does a `using`, and not actually installing to my `BUNDLE_PATH` folder. I was not able to figure this out, any help?

Comment: Note this won't work with a **gemspec**, per discussion [here](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/2911).

Comment: To disable the local override: `bundle config --delete local.GEM_NAME`

Comment: I had to remove version directive from the gem line to get this to work.

Comment: If you would like to use a different branch in development from production, you also have to set `bundle config disable_local_branch_check true` or Bundler will complain about the branch. Be careful with this though, as the checks are supposed to stop incorrect commits getting into `Gemfile.lock`. Docs here: http://bundler.io/v1.12/git.html

Comment: Note that the path provided in the `bundle` command should be the root directory of the other gem's source code

Answer (score 41):

You can also reference a local gem with git if you happen to be working on it.

```
gem 'foo',
  :git => '/Path/to/local/git/repo',
  :branch => 'my-feature-branch'
```

Then, if it changes I run

```
bundle exec gem uninstall foo
bundle update foo
```

But I am not sure everyone needs to run these two steps.

Comment: this is great, but is not that convenient if you're actively developing the gem... because you'll need to commit every change & `bundle uninstall <gem> && bundle install `, for every change you want reflected on your app

Answer (score 19):

In order to use local gem repository in a Rails project, follow the steps below:

1. Check if your gem folder is a git repository (the command is executed in the gem folder)

   ```
   git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree
   ```
2. Getting repository path (the command is executed in the gem folder)

   ```
   git rev-parse --show-toplevel
   ```
3. Setting up a local override for the rails application

   ```
   bundle config local.GEM_NAME /path/to/local/git/repository
   ```

   where `GEM_NAME` is the name of your gem and `/path/to/local/git/repository` is the output of the command in point `2`
4. In your application `Gemfile` add the following line:

   ```
   gem 'GEM_NAME', :github => 'GEM_NAME/GEM_NAME', :branch => 'master'
   ```
5. Running `bundle install` should give something like this:

   ```
   Using GEM_NAME (0.0.1) from git://github.com/GEM_NAME/GEM_NAME.git (at /path/to/local/git/repository)
   ```

   where `GEM_NAME` is the name of your gem and `/path/to/local/git/repository` from point `2`
6. Finally, run `bundle list`, not `gem list` and you should see something like this:

   ```
   GEM_NAME (0.0.1 5a68b88)
   ```

   where `GEM_NAME` is the name of your gem

---

A few important cases I am observing using:

```
Rails 4.0.2  
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux] 
Ubuntu 13.10  
RubyMine 6.0.3
```

- It seems `RubyMine` is not showing local gems as an external library. More information about the bug can be found  [here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-14542) and [here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-15026)
- When I am changing something in the local gem, in order to be loaded in the rails application I should `stop/start` the rails server
- If I am changing the `version` of the gem, `stopping/starting` the Rails server gives me an error. In order to fix it, I am specifying the gem version in the rails application `Gemfile` like this:

  ```
  gem 'GEM_NAME', '0.0.2', :github => 'GEM_NAME/GEM_NAME', :branch => 'master'
  ```

Answer (score 3):

You can reference gems with source:

`source: 'https://source.com', git repository (:github => 'git/url')`
and with local path

`:path => '.../path/gem_name'`.

You can learn more about [Gemfiles and how to use them]
(https://kolosek.com/rails-bundle-install-and-gemfile) in this article.

Answer (score -3):

If you want the branch too:

```
gem 'foo', path: "point/to/your/path", branch: "branch-name"
```

Comment: This doesn't work, generates an error:  `Only gems with a git source can specify a branch.`