# Developing gems and testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am new to developing Ruby gems, but I thought I'd give it a try.

Recently checking out the latest episode on Railscasts (http://railscasts.com/episodes/245-new-gem-with-bundler) I'm using Bundler to create my gem.

However I'm kind of clueless on how to test my gem.

Sure I could run **rake install** and then require it from **irb**, but this seems like a kind of slow workflow for me.

What I'd like to do is create a dummy Rails app and require the gem by referencing to it's source code. Is this possible? I'm sure I've read about it somewhere…

Thanks!

Comment: ps. Just noticed I could do a "require 'lib/my_gem'" in irb and I don't need to install it. But what if I want to do the same thing but in Rails? ds.

Answer (score 35):

You can include these lines in your Rakefile:

```
task :console do
  exec "irb -r mygem -I ./lib"
end
```

This will create a rake task to initialize a new irb session and preload your library. Now, all you have to do is:

```
$ rake console
```

Comment: Automated testing is great, but sometimes you need to poke around to figure out how things work.  This facilitates that nicely.  Replace `irb` with `pry` for even more bang for your buck.

Answer (score 24):

I can't recommend this guide from Ryan Bigg enough: http://bundler.io/v1.16/guides/creating_gem.html. It walks you through generating a gem using Bundler and setting up automated testing. You can develop your features without ever actually having to run your code manually. It's a workflow I'm using for my own gem development and has worked very well so far.

UPDATE: Rereading your question, it sounds like your gem is a Rails engine. I'd recommending looking at José Valim's EngineX. It's a generator that creates a gem with a dummy Rails app for testing (https://github.com/josevalim/enginex). If you already have a lot of code, http://keithschacht.com/creating-a-rails-3-engine-plugin-gem/ might help you setup a dummy app for testing.

Answer (score 13):

You can actually do:

`cd ~/my_gem_path` & `bundle console`

And this will be a quick test:

`My::Gem::VERSION`

Comment: Cool, if you are using `pry` instead of `irb`, there's an extra (on-time) step:
`bundle config console pry`

Answer (score 6):

You can [reference the gem locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487948/rails-3-how-can-i-specify-a-local-gem-in-my-gemfile), but if you don't want to run `bundle update` each time you change the gem, you can just require the files using their full path, or by moving (or symlinking) your gem into /vendor.

But to be honest, it sounds like you need to write some tests! ;) Manually testing each change you make is going to get tiresome and error-prone. If you're new to writing gems, have a look at the source of other popular gems and see how they're tested.

Comment: Haha, yes, after reading your answer and Joe's also, I can see the benefit of testing. Thanks!

Comment: Manual testing is great, but you also need to be able to manually walk through your code with an aim towards spotting use-cases your tests are missing.  Plus tests don't always perfectly reproduce 'live' work, and you have to go through the code at least once to find those.