# Testing my ruby module local changes without require_relative

Tags: ruby

I have a ruby module with a number of class files. Some of them load others. If the module is installed then require 'mymodule/foo' loads foo.rb from the installed module. But what if I want to test code changes that I have made without building a new gem and installing it?

I can do something like this but it's cumbersome:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'mymodule/foo'

# require 'foo.rb'
```

But I have to constantly remember to make sure the right one is commented when building the new gem. I am proficient in Ruby but by no means an expert.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493114/developing-gems-and-testing

Comment: I am assuming by "test" you mean manually debug because testing would be best done through a testing framework like `minitest` or `rspec`

Comment: I have a test script I run and I may want to only test one aspect of the package. Is a test framework the only way around this?

Comment: I am unsure what you mean by a "test script" but testing frameworks will allow you to run only specific tests or suites of tests

Comment: A small script that loads the module, creates an instance, and does stuff.