# Installing Ruby on Rails in a closed network on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I am a nb to RoR, I used the windows installer and it install fine. 
The problem is when RoR is trying to get out to http://rubygems.org, it can't get there.

So my question is where can I change where it sources that information and can I download those gems individually and place them into a directory for RoR to source?

I appreciate any help I have beating my head on this for days.

Comment: Are you using the command line to install gems or does your problem come with running Bundler which in turn can't get out to the internet?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that you are behind a proxy. Though your web browser and other various applications are probably set up to work through the proxy, RubyGems is not.

If you know your http proxy address and port, you can pass it as a command line argument to Ruby Gems.

Though I would suggest setting up your proxy as a system variable, you may not have that option as I also don't have that option at my current place of employment.

```
gem install rails --http-proxy=https://your.proxy.address:portnumber
```

Information about this at [RubyGems manual](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/13#page51).

EDIT:

There is a way to manually download and install a gem. It can be cumbersome and annoying but it is possible.

Go to [RubyGems.org](http://rubygems.org/) and use the search feature to find the gem you need. For this example, I will use Devise. On the page for [Devise](http://rubygems.org/gems/devise) is a download link. Download the gem and `cd` into that location. If you save it to `C:\manual_gems`, then `cd C:\manual_gems`.

The current version of Devise is 2.1.2. So, once you are in the folder you saved the gem to:

```
gem install devise-2.1.2.gem
```

Here comes the cumbersome part. You will notice an error saying that it requires dependencies. The RubyGems page also gives a list of dependencies. You will have to follow this same process for each of the dependencies before finally being able to install the gem.

For instance, Devise requires Warden which in turn requires ActionPack, ActiveSupport, Rack-SSL, Rake, RDoc, and Thor (which you may already have installed if you have Rails). It's a recursive trip that RubyGems and Bundler take care of for you.

When all of that is in place, you can modify your GemFile in your Rails app to point to the local gems. I have not tested it but there is an accepted answer on a [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487948/how-can-i-specify-a-local-gem-in-my-gemfile) on the topic which provides the solution of:

```
gem 'devise', path: 'path/to/devise'
```

Again, cumbersome but if you really want to get a Rails app up and running in a limited environment such as that you imply, this should either work or get you well on your way.

Comment: I wish that was the case. I do not have access to the anything outside.

Comment: Is there anyway to get what RoR wants by downloading it and uploading it to my server. Then pointing RoR to that location so I can finish the install?

Comment: I updated my answer with a manual means of downloading the gems and installing them.

Comment: Thank you I will give it try...I let know about my progress. Again thanks for being quick and helpful.