# How to use gem from local directory

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems

I installed gem "cupertino" and after that I changed some piece of code.

Now I want to use new copy of gem. It's located in `~/cupertino/cupertino-0.9.5.gem`

I already have tried to change path by this:

```
gem "cupertino", :path => "~/cupertino/cupertino-0.9.5.gem"
```

but Bash said that "No such file or directory". What is wrong?

P.S: I'm newbie in MacOS ._.

**upated:**

```
gem "cupertino", :path => "/cupertino/cupertino-0.9.5.gem"
```

didn't help

Comment: This is a super-basic question, but it a known trap for a new developer.  I'm not sure is should be closed

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I specify a local gem in my Gemfile?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487948/how-can-i-specify-a-local-gem-in-my-gemfile)

Comment: i saw that, but it didn't help me :(

Comment: You didn't use the full path to the local gemfile.  `/cupertino` isn't where it is, it's in your `home_dir` under `cupertino` (something like `/Users/your_username/cupertino`

Comment: ok, i tried this: gem "cupertino", :path => "/Users/admin/cupertino/cupertino-0.9.5.gem" ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Unknown command cupertino,

Comment: That's an entirely different problem.  You probably need to install that gem locally first `gem install /Users/admin/cupertino/cupertino-0.9.5.gem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gem doesn't understand `~`, you'll need to use the full path to the gem.