# Local gem class is not found in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, ruby-2.0

I have written a generator which creates the following ruby file and folder:

```
app/tests/test.rb
```

in the `test.rb` file I have a `Test` class which looks like this:

```
class Test < MyCustomModule::MyCustomClass::Base
...
end
```

Now, I want to use its functionality in one of the `show.html.erb` files creating new instance like this:

```
Test.new(...).render(...).html_safe
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
uninitialized constant MyCustomModule::MyCustomClass::Base
```

I have use the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14167368/1080354) to link my gem and my rails application. It seems to work as I am able to use the generator, but the gem module and class are not seen in the rails application.

Could anyone tell how to fix this issue?

---

I have try to follow the tips posted [here](http://www.williambharding.com/blog/technology/rails-3-autoload-modules-and-classes-in-production/) but still nothing changed:

1. Adding `config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]` in `application.rb` file
2. I have created my gem structure looking at `CarrierWave` gem, so the naming should be correct
3. I try to disable `config.threadsafe!` but it is already disabled since `config.cache_classes` and `config.eager_load` are set to false in development

   > DEPRECATION WARNING: config.threadsafe! is deprecated. Rails
   >   applications behave by default as thread safe in production as long as
   >   config.cache_classes and config.eager_load are set to true.

Also, looking at [adding-asset-to-your-gems](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#adding-assets-to-your-gems) rails documentation, it is said that:

> A good example of this is the jquery-rails gem which comes with Rails
>   as the standard JavaScript library gem. This gem contains an engine
>   class which inherits from Rails::Engine. By doing this, Rails is
>   informed that the directory for this gem may contain assets and the
>   app/assets, lib/assets and vendor/assets directories of this engine
>   are added to the search path of Sprockets.

So, I have done this, and put my model class file in `assets` folder, but the result is the same.

---

The following screenshots demonstrate my real case:

1. The screenshot below displays my gem file structure

   [image]
2. Here you can see how I am loading the gem in my Rails application `Gemfile`:

   ```
   gem 'thumbnail_hover_effect', '0.0.3', github: 'thumbnail_hover_effec/thumbnail_hover_effec', branch: 'master'
   ```
3. Then I am using the gem generator a ruby file with a cutstom name in `app/thumbnails/test.rb` folder with the following code:

   ```
   class Test < ThumbnailHoverEffect::Image::Base
   ...
   end
   ```

   and trying to use the `Test` class gives me `uninitialized constant        ThumbnailHoverEffect::Image::Base` error.
4. Back in the gem files, these are how the `thumbnail_hover_effect` file looks like

   ```
   require 'thumbnail_hover_effect/version'
   require 'thumbnail_hover_effect/engine'
   require 'thumbnail_hover_effect/image'

   module ThumbnailHoverEffect
      # Your code goes here...
   end
   ```

   and hoe the `image` file looks like:

   ```
    module ThumbnailHoverEffect
    #
       class Image
       ...
      end
    end
   ```

Comment: can you provide real-world code please? what's the exact class-name, what are the file-names? are you sure that everything get's loaded properly (i doubt it).

Comment: @phoet Sorry, for the late replay. I have added some real code, let me know if you need to know something else.

Comment: and where is `ThumbnailHoverEffect::Image::Base` supposed to be coming from?

Comment: @phoet From the `image.rb` file of the gem.

Comment: so why don't you show the code for the thing that seems to be causing the error?

Comment: @phoet I might be wrong but as I have understood this error is caused by because the gem `module` and the `class` are not visible in my application, not because there is an error in the `immage` class itself. Are you saying that I should debug the class code first?

Comment: where is the definition of `MyCustomModule::MyCustomClass::Base`?

Comment: i'm saying that if you have an error saying `uninitialized constant        ThumbnailHoverEffect::Image::Base` you should show the code for `ThumbnailHoverEffect::Image::Base` and how it's included in your code-base.

Comment: @phoet I am sorry about this. I was able to understand what are you asking after I have understood what was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've posted here there is no `ThumbnailHoverEffect::Image::Base` defined.  Rails autoloading conventions (which you should not be depending on a gem btw, more on that later) would be looking for this file in `thumbnail_hover_effect/image/base.rb`, but the directory structure you printed does not have that.  Of course you could define the class in `thumbnail_hover_effect/image.rb` and it would work, but the abridged snippet you posted does not show that.  So where is `ThumbnailHoverEffect::Image::Base` defined?

If it's in `thumbnail_hover_effect/image/base.rb` then that would indicate the file is not being loaded.  You can sanity check this by putting a `puts 'loading this stupid file'` at the top of `thumbnail_hover_effect/image/base.rb`.  That will allow you to bisect the problem by seeing whether there is a problem with your definition of the class, or whether the problem is with loading the proper files.  Debugging is all about bisecting the problem.

Comment: it does not even look like there is a `ThumbnailHoverEffect::Image::Base`

Comment: Of course there is no `ThumbnailHoverEffect::Image::Base` - I haven't defined such class at all. I ended in this foolish situation because I am ruby newbie who decided to use a working gem structure and code as a template.