# Migrating Tumblr to Jekyll not uploading photo posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tumblr, jekyll

I am trying to migrate a Tumblr blog to a Jekyll Blog and I am using the migration code provided by Jekyll here: http://import.jekyllrb.com/docs/tumblr/. It is migrating everything except photos in photo posts. Am I missing something with this specific migrator or is there a better way to do this?

```
$ ruby -rubygems -e 'require "jekyll-import";
JekyllImport::Importers::Tumblr.run({
  "url"            => "http://myblog.tumblr.com",
  "format"         => "html", # or "md"
  "grab_images"    => true,  # whether to download images as well.
  "add_highlights" => false,  # whether to wrap code blocks (indented 4 spaces) in a Liquid "highlight" tag
  "rewrite_urls"   => false   # whether to write pages that redirect from the old Tumblr paths to the new Jekyll paths
})'
```

Comment: There is an [open issue](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-import/pull/114) which looks like a possible cause. As it has been sitting open for a while I'm going to take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in my comment, there is a [known issue](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-import/pull/114) importing pages which contain multiple images. I have taken a look at the issue and done a little work on a fix, with the hope this is accepted in the project.

In the mean time; if you are able to use [bundler](http://bundler.io/) with a [local gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487948/how-can-i-specify-a-local-gem-in-my-gemfile) to execute the command, [my fork](https://github.com/dhutchison/jekyll-import) of the project contains the fix (which I've checked works against your tumbler site).

My test Gemfile is:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'github-pages'
gem 'stringex'
gem 'jekyll-import', :path => '/Users/david/Development/Local Projects/jekyll-import'
gem 'jekyll-sitemap'
```

The command, once bundler is installed and the Gemfile configured, would be:

```
bundle exec ruby -rubygems -e 'require "jekyll-import";
JekyllImport::Importers::Tumblr.run({
  "url"            => "http://mysite.tumblr.com",
  "format"         => "html", # or "md"
  "grab_images"    => true,  # whether to download images as well.
  "add_highlights" => false,  # whether to wrap code blocks (indented 4 spaces) in a Liquid "highlight" tag
  "rewrite_urls"   => false   # whether to write pages that redirect from the old Tumblr paths to the new Jekyll paths
})'
```

Comment: Your gemfile worked perfectly BTW. I even saw an update got merged into Master that wasn't yours and that wasn't working for me. Thank you!

Comment: it's too bad this only works with html format. would be nice to go directly to markdown WITH images.