# How to install gems from Gemfile?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, code-coverage

I want to add code coverage to my project and sign up coveralls.io and create Gemfile with:

```
gem 'coveralls', require: false
```

but how can I install the gem from Gemfile?

Comment: Are you using [Bundler](http://bundler.io/)? That's the usual way to install ruby gems.

Comment: No, I don't use Bundler, do I need to use to get gems from gemfile? Are gemfiles bound ot Bundler?

Comment: @jcubic: yes, gemfiles are handled by bundler.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

run the command `bundle install` in your shell, once you have your Gemfile created.

This command will look your Gemfile and install the relevant Gems on the indicated versions.

The Gemfiles are installed because in your Gemfile you are pointing out the source where the gems can be downloaded from.

Your can create a Gemfile just by typing `bundle init` in your shell

I add a Gemfile example for your reference:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"  # where gems will be downloaded from
ruby "2.2.3"  # ruby version, change for the one you use

gem "sinatra"
gem "sinatra-flash"
gem "sinatra-partial"
gem "bcrypt"
gem "dm-validations"
gem "dm-transactions"
gem "data_mapper"
gem "dm-postgres-adapter"
gem "pg"
gem "database_cleaner"

group :test do   # you can make groups for test, development, production..
  gem "rspec"
  gem "capybara"
  gem "rspec-sinatra"
  gem "cucumber"
  gem "coveralls", require: false
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint! Do you know how can I set gem / bundle to always work on  local packages not the system ones? :-)

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487948/how-can-i-specify-a-local-gem-in-my-gemfile

Answer (score 38):

First install bundler if you don't have it

`gem install bundler` or `sudo gem install bundler` if you don't have the required permissions. Bundler is a gem that manages gem dependencies.

then you can follow the above instruction for creating the gemfile, after which you can issue the command

`bundle install`