# Use third party ruby library in my calabash tests, but get error

Tags: android, ruby, cucumber, calabash, calabash-android

My calabash android test project has the following structure:

```
-- myApp.apk
-- features (directory)
          |-- my-feature-1-file-name.feature
          |-- step_definitions (directory)
          |      calabash_steps.rb
          |-- support (directory)
          |      thirdPartyLib.rb
```

My calabash test steps need to use a third party library **thirdPartyLib.rb**. As you see above, under `features/` directory, I have a `support/` directory, there, I have a **thirdPartyLib.rb** ruby file.

Inside **thirdPartyLib.rb** , the 1st line of code is this:

```
require 'jmespath'
...
```

When I go to my project root, and run the test by command `calabash-android run myApp.apk DEBUG=1` , I get the following error:

```
DEBUG: Setting Android SDK location to $ANDROID_HOME
DEBUG: Android SDK location set to '/Users/John/Library/Android/sdk'
DEBUG: Set aapt path to '/Users/John/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.3/aapt'
DEBUG: Set zipalign path to '/Users/John/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.3/zipalign'
DEBUG: Set adb path to '/Users/John/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb'
DEBUG: Set android jar path to '/Users/John/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-24/android.jar'
DEBUG: Setting Java SDK location to $JAVA_HOME
DEBUG: Java SDK location set to '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home'
DEBUG: Found java on PATH
DEBUG: Set java path to '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'
DEBUG: Found keytool on PATH
DEBUG: Set keytool path to '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/keytool'
DEBUG: Found jarsigner on PATH
DEBUG: Set jarsigner path to '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jarsigner'
cannot load such file -- jmespath (LoadError)

/Users/John/.calabash/sandbox/Rubies/2.1.6-p336/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Users/John/.calabash/sandbox/Rubies/2.1.6-p336/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Users/John/my-calabash-test/features/support/thirdPartyLib.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
...
```

So, it is a loading error, it looks like calabash-android cannot load file `jmespath (LoadError)`that is declared in **thirdPartLib.rb** . How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: Is the jmespath gem installed?

Comment: No. It is not. But I can't install just the gem, because I need to upload my calabash test project to cloud to run, I need all the 3rd party library ruby files put under `support/` directory of my test project

Comment: Can you add jmespath to your Gemfile?

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth, I am not sure, I can have a try, but I don't find how to add it to Gemfile

Comment: Do you have a Gemfile? If so you could add it to your question. I don't know if you do or not, but if you did it would probably be the way to fix the problem.

Comment: I can create a Gemfile, but I mean in Gemfile, how to add the jmepath library?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the jmespath gem to use it.  To install it you need to add it to your gemfile.  You can specify a local copy of a gem as follows

```
gem "foo", :path => "/path/to/foo"
```

Example taken from this question / answer - [How can I specify a local gem in my Gemfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487948/how-can-i-specify-a-local-gem-in-my-gemfile)

Comment: But calabahs-android cannot load/install the gems. My problem is how to make calabash-android be able to load the gems so that my test code which invoke the 3rd party gem functions can run.

Comment: If you do a bundle install before it runs, it should be able to load them.  Is that not working?

Comment: No, that is not working, I can run my standalone ruby script which has `require aws-sdk`, but if I start running calabash test which loads my standalone ruby file, it complains undefined module `aws-sdk`.

Comment: Just to check you have run `bundle install` then `bundle exec calabash-android run myApp.apk DEBUG=1`

Comment: How did you get on?