# How to make local gem avaliable to the rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, filepath

I have a `rails` application. which uses a `private gem` from the `github`.

in `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'xyz',
  git: "https://#{ENV['GITHUB_TOKEN']}:x-oauth-basic@github.com/cvb/xyz.git",
  branch: :development
```

I added some modifications to this `gem` locally. in order to test those modifications, i want to change those `remote gem path's` to the `local gem` path(the application and the gem are present in the same directory). but i don't know how to mention this `local gem` path in the gem file. can any body help me with the syntax, like what path should be added to the gemfile(like relative path or absolute path).

Comment: its not a duplicate question. its my requirement. unfortunately, i did not seen the above question.

Comment: One of the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14167368/8255744) in the duplicate it almost exactly what you're asking for. The most recent docs for it are [here](http://bundler.io/v1.15/man/bundle-config.1.html#LOCAL-GIT-REPOS)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, try this:

1. clone the gem from `github.com/cvb/xyz.git`
2. modify it as you like
3. then add this locally modified gem in your application, like:

> gem "xyz", path: "/local/gem/directory/in/your/machine"

Then `bundle` and feel your change.

Cheers!