# How to require chained local gems in a ruby appliction

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am working on developing multiple interdependent gems. Usually I use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487948/how-can-i-specify-a-local-gem-in-my-gemfile) for using a local version of `Gem B`, which `Gem A` depends on. When I was working on some changes that also changed part of `Gem C` which is a `Gem B` dependency I got the following error when trying to run `Gem A`:

`'require': cannot load such file -- Gem C`

`Gem B` has that local version required.

How can I get around this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is adding a line in `Gem A`'s `Gemfile` requiring the local version of `Gem C`.